# How to create an multidimensional array in Laravel/PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to store some values in one array, where each element has its child element.

Please find the code:

```
$children = $user->relations()->wherePlanId($selectplan)->get();
foreach($children as $ch)
{
  $child[] = $ch->pivot->child;
  $subuser = User::find($ch->pivot->child);
  if($subuser){
      $subchildren = $subuser->relations()->wherePlanId($selectplan)->get();
      foreach($subchildren as $subchild)
      {
        $subchildid[] = $subchild->pivot->child;
      }
   }
  else
  {
    $subchildid[] = NULL;
  }
}
```

I want to store something like `child['parent_element']['child_element']`
i.e expected array format

```
child[1][2]
child[1][3]
child[1][4]
child[1][5]
child[2][6]
child[2][7]
.
.
child[3][12]
```

Help me out. Thanks

Comment: what is your expected array format?

Comment: what's the structure your `$children`?

Comment: what should be the value of each of your index `child['parent_element']['child_element']`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your table data is

`tblusers`

```
id   name
 1   John
 2   Doe
 3   Carl
 4   Jose
 5   Bill
 6   James
 7   Karl
```

`tblparents`

```
id  parent  child
1    1       2
2    1       3
3    1       4
4    1       5
5    2       6
6    2       7
```

First: declare a variable which will store your array

```
$child_arr = [];
```

then loop your parent array

```
foreach($children as $ch) {
    // do something
}
```

Inside the loop of your parent loop the children your loop parent

```
foreach($subchildren as $subchild) {
    $child_arr['your parent id']['your child id'] = 'your desired value';
}
```

so your code would be like this

```
$child_arr = [];
$children = $user->relations()->wherePlanId($selectplan)->get();
foreach($children as $ch) {
    $parent_id = $ch->pivot->child;
    $subuser = User::find($ch->pivot->child);
    if($subuser) {
        $subchildren = $subuser->relations()->wherePlanId($selectplan)->get();
        foreach($subchildren as $subchild) {
            $child_id = $subchild->pivot->child;
            $child_arr[$parent_id][$child_id] = $subchild;
        }
    } else {
        $child_arr[$parent_id] = null;
    }
}
```

the result would be like this

```
array(
    [1] => array(
          [2] => 'value',
          [3] => 'value',
          [4] => 'value',
          [5] => 'value',
    ),
    [2] => array(
          [6] => 'value',
          [7] => 'value'
    ),
    etc...
)
```

or you can just leave `'value'` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
foreach($children as $ch)
{
  $child[] = $ch->pivot->child;
  $subuser = User::find($ch->pivot->child);
  if($subuser){
      $subchildren = $subuser->relations()->wherePlanId($selectplan)->get();
      foreach($subchildren as $subchild)
      {
        $subchildid[$ch->pivot->child] = $subchild->pivot->child;
      }
   }
  else
  {
    $subchildid[] = NULL;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is overlapping the array value and only showing the last value!