# Laravel from for each to array how?

Tags: php, laravel

this is the result of a Foreach loop get method using dd$($value),

**Questions:** how do i convert this inside my controller into an array and store it into my database

**Example:** [**Lead_id1=Subjectid1 , Lead_id2=Subjectid1, Lead_id3=Subjectid1**]
so on and so fort..

**Note:** Lead_id and Subject_id are both **FK** there for the value must be integer Not **String**

**Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $value=$request->all();
    $subjects = $value['Subject_id'] ?? [];
    $leads = $value['Lead_id'] ?? [];
    $data = [];
     foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
     $data[] = array_combine($leads, array_fill(0, count($leads), $subject));

    $scores=new Score;
    $scores->Subject_id=$request->input('Subject_id');
    $scores->Lead_id=$request->input('Lead_id');
   dd($scores);
    $scores->save();
}
```

**this is the result**[image][image]

**Score Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Score extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [
        'id',
        'Year_id',
        'Term_id',
        'Level_id',
        'Classes_id',
        'Subject_id',
        'Lead_id',
    ]; 
}
```

Comment: The subject id will always stay the same? I mean a single value in the array?

Comment: @Sougata Bose yes i same as the picture above,  as long as what subject is being selected from the loop will display

Comment: Kindly check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905044/how-to-create-an-multidimensional-array-in-laravel-php) link

Comment: can you show us your **foreach loop** ???

Comment: "how do i convert this inside my controller into an array": it already is an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said `Lead_id and Subject_id` both are foreign key then you can simply use ManyToMany relation in laravel and save the data accordingly

> Subject Model

```
class Subject extends Model{
   public function leads(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Lead::class, 'scores', 'Subject_id', 'Lead_id');
   }
}
```

> Lead Model

```
class Lead extends Model{
   public function subjects(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class, 'scores', 'Lead_id', 'Subject_id');
   }  
}
```

**Questions: how do i convert this inside my controller into an array and store it into my database**

```
foreach($data['Subject_id'] as $subjectId){
    $subject = Subject::find($subjectId);
    $leadids = $data['Lead_id'];
    $subject->leads()->attach($leadids);
}
```

For details check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: @Grace i have updated answer with the required tables in your database

Comment: oh you have `scores` table for relationship right ?

Comment: subjects[subject_id],leads[subject_id] <--this athe the main table then this-->Score[id, Subject_id, Lead_id] is the many table where i want to store the data

Comment: `Score[id, Subject_id, Lead_id]` what is the table name ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173943/discussion-between-rkj-and-grace).

Comment: scores then Model is Score

Comment: Yes it work haha finaly my head already stop itchy hahaha thank you so much @rkj and to other who contribute there answer big help guys thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You can try -

```
$temp = [];
$subject = !empty($value['Subject_id'][0]) ? $value['Subject_id'][0] : null; // extract the subject id
// Loop through lead ids
foreach($value['Lead_id'] as $lead) {
    $temp[$lead] = $subject; // store subject id fro lead ids
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try following :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $value=$request->all();
    $subjects = $value['Subject_id'] ?? [];
    $leads = $value['Lead_id'] ?? [];
    $data = [];

    foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
        $data[] = array_combine($leads, array_fill(0, count($leads), $subject));
    }

    foreach ($data as $load => $subject) {
        $scores = new Score;
        $scores->Subject_id = $subject;
        $scores->Lead_id = $load;
        $scores->save();
        dd($scores);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you upload your `Score` Model?

Comment: Updated my question bro

Answer (score -2):

convert the array first into a json string

```
json_encode($array);
```

before store it to the database

Comment: what this thing will do?

Comment: convert your array to a json string so you can store them unto your database and then you can just use json_decode($db_results); to convert it unto a regular array. if you wanna store them you can use blob but that would be overpower and blobs are heavy